# Convert a string to an object with attribute to get its value

Tags: python

I have a probably very simple question, but unfortunately I can't find an answer to it.

How can I convert this string

```
"bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_gtao"
```

to this object with attribute:

```
bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_gtao
```

to store its value like this:

```
Val = bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_gtao
```

(True or False in this example) ?

Comment: you could just use `eval` like this: `Val = eval("bpy.context.scene.eevee.use_gtao")` but be careful never to use `eval` if you aren't absolutely sure you know what you are about to evaluate

Comment: What is *bpy*? Please show the rest of the code. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Nullman: Well, that was fast! Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @CristiFati: You're probably right about that, but it's just not relevant to this question because it's really just about the conversion. bpy is blender python.